# Post build event write to VS output console

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible somehow write to VS output console from post build event script? Something like:

`@echo $(ProjectDir)`

Answer (score 7):

Yes this will work fine.

I had the same question and found that echo works fine to write to output in the VS build events.